# Flutter fill size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've a custom widget that I paint as follows

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: CustomPaint(
      painter: MyPainter(),
    ),
  );
}
```

But that trows an error during painting, namely that the given size is of `Size(0,0)`. When I add hardcoded sizes to the container

```
return Container(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MyPainter(),
  ),
);
```

Then it gets painted nicely. But I don't want it to be 200x200. I want the width to fill the screen and the height to be as large as the width (i.e. a square width).
I also tried removing the width and height and adding `constraints: BoxConstraints.expand()` to the container, but to no prevail nor does switching `Container` for `FittedBox`.

Comment: use .  width: double.infinity .   and   height: double.infinity

Comment: than it raises an exception `BoxConstraints forces an infinite width and infinite height.`

Comment: give a `child:` to `CustomPaint` - for example `SizedBox.expand()`

Comment: @pskink no, threw another exception about infinite widths

Comment: `child: CustomPaint(
    painter: MyPainter(), child: SizedBox.expand(),
  ),` - no exception is thrown and `size` passed to `MyPainter.paint()` is correct